# root pages#home or root posts#index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner on Ruby on Rails and I have a small question.

I am currently creating an application allowing me to list my posts with an upvote system,... . Currently I create my `homepage` with `root pages#home`.

But I have the impression that I may have to do my `homepage` with `root posts#index` ..

Because when I look at some tutorials I feel that it's easier to put the infinite scroll, search filters with ajax, ranking by popular or newest, opening my posts in modal bootstrap, ... with `root posts#index` ...

So I hesitate to change everything ... opinions? :)
What is better for the long term ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can specify any page you want as the root.   The naming has nothing to do with how it works, just a convention with common setups.  You could root to `posts#new` if you wanted.

Comment: @RockwellRice Actually but I asked myself this question (as a beginner) because I encountered some problems by wanting to add on my homepage an infinite scroll or an ajax filter for example.

And I noticed that most of the tutorials or explanations about this still had for root posts#index.

As Ryan Brunner and Michael Arkhipov say it may make more sense to work with root posts#index if my homepage only includes listings.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, either approach will work and there's no functionality gained or lost by using a "generic" page or a resourceful route (which is what you're getting when you say `posts#index`)

Semantically though, you should organize your controllers in a way that corresponds to the function of a page. `pages#home` carries little or no semantic meaning. Someone reading the contents of `rails routes` is not going to be able to infer anything about what that page is beyond "a home page". `posts#index` does carry more semantic meaning - it strongly implies that the main purpose of this page is to list posts.

If your site is structured like this, i.e. your "home" page is mostly concerned with listing posts, then using `posts#index` makes sense. If it's more of a generic dashboard that does a bunch of things (including listing posts), something like `pages#home` might make more sense to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another page with `posts`, you should use `pages#home`, but if you show `posts` only on home page, using root on `posts#index` make sense.

Comment: I use other pages with posts like library or statistics but they are pages specific to the current user.

But I only display posts on the home page with categories.

So I think it's better to go back to a posts#index.

thank you for your reply